# Por que mi consulta en asp.net no me muestra los resultados

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, base-de-datos

quisiera ver si alguien me puede decir que esta fallando en el codigo ya busque posibles soluciones pero no me han funcionado, en si se supone que si me hace la consulta pero me muestra que no se encontraron resultados a continuacion dejo el codigo:

```
public DataTable buscarEqOtro(string ddbuscar, string TextBox2)
{


    using (sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Soporte"].ToString()))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sqlCon.Open();
        string.Format("select * from Equipo_Otros where {0} like '%@TextBox2%'", ddbuscar);
        //String consulta = "select * from Equipo_Otros where @ddbuscar like '%@TextBox2%'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("select * from Equipo_Otros where {0} like '%@TextBox2%'", ddbuscar), sqlCon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddbuscar", ddbuscar);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextBox2", TextBox2);
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        //adap.Fill(dt);
        return dt;

    }
}
```

y aca esta donde me muestra el resultado

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtbl = equipo.buscarEqOtro(ddbuscar.SelectedValue, TextBox2.Text);

    if (dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        gvEqOt.DataSource = dtbl;   
        gvEqOt.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        dtbl.Rows.Add(dtbl.NewRow());
        gvEqOt.DataSource = dtbl;
        gvEqOt.DataBind();
        gvEqOt.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
        gvEqOt.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        gvEqOt.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = dtbl.Columns.Count;
        gvEqOt.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No se encontro ningun registro";
        gvEqOt.Rows[0].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El estándar SQL, siguiendo tu necesidad es:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tabla
WBERE Campo like '%TextoABuscar%'
```

Si el campo viene definido por la variable `ddbuscar` y el texto a buscar por la variable `TextBox2` entonces

```
string.Format("select * from Equipo_Otros where {0} like '%{1}%'", ddbuscar, TextBox2);
```

Lo que hacías no es concatenar la variable `TextBox2`, estabas buscando siempre el texto "TextBox2".